# How to move focus with in columns inside one grid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have grid designed something like below:

This is xaml used for a grid:-
I am using devexpress gridcontrol in my application.

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyAddresses}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Cell"></dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="MyAddress" Header="Address" MinWidth="725">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RowData.Row}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="250"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="250"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address"/>
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="2000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding PostAddress}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="Country" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PostCountry}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="City" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="100" Text="{Binding City}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Text="Postal Code" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="15" Text="{Binding PostalCode}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Text="Subdivision" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="100" Text="{Binding Subdivision}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Email" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="254" Text="{Binding Email1}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Text="Phone" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="20" Text="{Binding Phone1}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Text="Phone" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="20" Text="{Binding Phone2}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4" Text="Fax" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="50" Text="{Binding Fax1}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="4" Text="Telex" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="100" Text="{Binding Telex}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="4" Text="Web" />
                            <dxe:TextEdit Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="255" Text="{Binding Web}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="NewField"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

In first cell I have few columns, I want to move cursor with in first cell and then jump to second cell.

Can someone please help.
![enter image description here][1]
My grid looks like above. I have focus on first field . On pressing tab I want focus move to City field not to next cell which is New Field.

Any suggestions?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENqqP.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue is already discussed at DevExpress Support Center: [Tabbing issue in CellTemplate](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q571924). Thus, you can use the solution provided by the DevExpress Support Team.

The main idea of this solution is in custom handling of the `TabbedView.PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
void TableView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab) {
        // do some custom handling
        e.Handled = true; // avoid TabbedView's default focus processing
    }
}
```